# Doubt from Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

If we have to make graph for reversible adiabatic process involving an ideal gas in a P - T curve then how to proceed ?
My try : As we know the relation between P and T in Adiabatic process , differentiated that and tried to find the relation but it went too long and also difficult.
[image]

Is this correct

Comment: What did you want to achieve with derivatives? I don't think you need them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did was correct, but all you really needed to do was write $$T=CP^{\frac{\gamma-1}{\gamma}}$$

Comment: Can you explain me how it's graph will be drawn and what is it's slope

Comment: It's a straight line on a log-log plot with a positive slope of $(\gamma - 1)/\gamma$